# Cannot integrate Bootstrap in my Ruby on Rails (version 4.0.0) app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have tried multiple methods, followed many tutorials but nothing is taking effect on my Rails application. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'paperclip', '~>3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~>4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

The `application.css.scss` goes like

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

The `application.js` file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The `index.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="posts index">
    <h1>Welcome to The Incognito Social Network</h1>
    <%=link_to("Say Something!", {:action=> 'new'}, :class=>'action new')%>

    <table class="listing" summary="All posts">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Post #<%=post.id%>   </td>
        <td><%=post.text%></td>
        <%if post.image_file_name%>
        <td>
        <%=image_tag post.image.url %>
        </td>
        <%end%>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to("Like", '#', :class=>'action upvote')%></td>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
    </table>


</div>
```

I have tried writing `layout false` and `#layout false` in my controllers. None of it takes effect.

The rails app has no change on it. I tried putting bootstrap code in my index.html.erb files but it does not appear with the Bootstrap style. It appears as if its simple HTML. Anybody knows how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add your `index.html.erb` file?

Comment: @Tobias I have updated the question with the index.html.erb file

Comment: It does't look like you've applying any Bootstrap classes for a [table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables). Have you tried `<table class="table listing" summary="All posts">`?

Comment: @vanburen Still no effect on my rails app. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you inspected the page to see if Bootstraps CSS is loading?

Comment: @vanburen Yes, I just did. No sign of Bootstrap!

Comment: Do you have a link tag for your stylesheets in your application.html.erb? **<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>**

Comment: @vanburen I had disabled the layout by putting `layout false` in the controller. I commented it out and this is what I get when I boot up my server `Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES5. Please install node.js.` And there is no node.js gem in the Ruby Gem depository, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so I installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and restarted my computer. Moreover here is my updated `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mysql2','~> 0.3.11'
gem 'paperclip', '~>3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~>4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~>0.10.0' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I also figured out that I had to comment out `layout false` in the controller to get the Bootstrap working. Thank you @Tobias and @vanburen for your help.

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out and don't forget to mark you own answer as complete so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

As @vanburen already wrote: You have to add the `table` class to your `table` tag.

So replace

```
<table class="listing" summary="All posts">
```

with

```
<table class="table listing" summary="All posts">
```

Now bootstrap should recognize the table and change it's style.

You will find more information in the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

Happy coding :).

Comment: Still no effect on my rails app. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this an open source project? If yes, could you add the Repo URL?